# Why can a user register without giving a value for a "required attribute" in AWS Cognito?

Tags: authentication, attributes, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I was under the impression that a user had to give a value if you marked the attribute as required. Somehow I can register without providing any value for given_name, family_name or birthdate?

From the documentation:
"
Note

When a standard attribute is marked as required, a user cannot register unless a value for the attribute is provided. Administrators can create users without giving values for required attributes by using the AdminCreateUser API. An attribute cannot be switched between required and not required after a user pool has been created."

I am not sure if this is because I have configured the Cognito UserPool with Amplify? Have I missed something?

[image]

Comment: "Administrators can create users without giving values for required attributes by using the AdminCreateUser API"  - I would guess its using the admin functions to create the user.

Comment: I set up the Cognito UserPool in the terminal using the Amplify Cli. Do you know how I would find out if it's using the admin functions?

Comment: I am not certain on your set-up. But with the call to Auth.signup in amplify there is a parameter called validationData, which takes in an array. I can't seem to find any examples but I believe the solution to this issue is that. If you are passing other attributes to validate them you must use the validationData array.  The api reference for the code for signup can be seen here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/4644b432/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L209